# how to disable syntax checking of google api in Intellij IDEA

Tags: javascript, java, google-maps, intellij-idea

How to disable syntax checking of google api in Intellij IDEA.
Image attached

[image: how to disable spell checking google api in Intellij IDEA]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the suppress inspection comments on the preceding line (`//noinspection JSUnresolvedVariable,JSUnresolvedFunction`). Though this generally requires a comment before each line you want to suppress.

The highlighting you show means that Intellij simply does not know anything about the libary you are using. So as an alternative, you could try going the opposite route and *adding* the library to Intellij to enable proper syntax checking:

Under Settings > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries, look for the google api listed in the available js libraries and click the checkbox to enable it.
If it doesn't exist in this list for some reason you can try finding it under the "Download.." menu or adding the file yourself in the "Add.." menu.
Worth noting that this setting is on a per-project basis, so you'd have to set it up for each different project you are using the api with.

Comment: Thank you phaze0.  Settings > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries, and downloading googlemap api helped me.